# converting my current code to web Service

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I have the following code that I want to convert to a web service.

I get `<string xmlns="http://company.net/">[]</string>` when running web service, no search result just `[]`

What does that mean?

Old Code:

```
Sub Search(ByVal intSearchType As Search.enmSearchType)
Try

Dim objSearch As New Search             'search object
Dim objSearchInst As New Search         'search object
Dim intResult As Integer                'function call results
Dim objList As New ArrayList            'array list of search objects

'hide search panel and check at least 3 characters entered in search field
panSearch.Visible = True
If Len(txtSearch.Text) < 3 Then
    txtResults.Text = "Enter at least 3 characters to do a search"
    Exit Sub
End If

'do keyword search
intResult = objSearch.SearchByKeyword(txtSearch.Text, Session("Person"), Session("Office"), Session("Organisation"), _
                                      Session("Role"), intSearchType, objList)

'if error is returned show user and clear results
If intResult <> 0 Then
    txtResults.Text = "Oops. There was a problem performing the search, please try again later"
    Exit Sub
End If
txtResults.Text = ""

 'show results for contacts
    For Each objSearchInst In objList
        txtResults.Text += "<a href='#' class=lnks onclick=""return OpenWindow('../contactmanagement/contact.aspx?PersonRef=" & objSearchInst.Return1 & "',750,600)""><b>#" & objSearchInst.Return1 & "</b>: " & objSearchInst.Return2 & " " & objSearchInst.Return3 & "</a><br/>"
    Next

End If

'no results found show user
If txtResults.Text = "" Then
    txtResults.Text = "no matching records found"
End If
```

Catch ex As Exception
    txtResults.Text = "Oops. There was a problem performing the search, please try again later"
End Try
End Sub

What I have tried and does not work is:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
    Public Function ContactGet(ByVal searchField As String) As String

    Dim objSearch As New ArrayList
    Dim objSearching As New Search
    Dim intResult As Integer

    Try

        intResult = objSearching.SearchByKeyword(searchField, str_person_ref, str_office_ref, str_organization_ref, _
                                         str_role_ref, company.ETMyProperty.Search.enmSearchType.enmContact, objSearch)

            Dim objContact As New Person
            Dim dt As New DataTable("Contacts")

            Dim col_Name As New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add(col_Name)

            Dim col_Mobile As New DataColumn("Mobile", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add(col_Mobile)

            Dim col_Office As New DataColumn("ContactNum", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add(col_Office)

            Dim col_Category As New DataColumn("Category", GetType(String))
            dt.Columns.Add(col_Category)

            Dim dr As DataRow

            'add new row to datatable
        'For Each objSearching In objSearch

        'For Each drow As DataRow In objSearch
        '    dr = dt.NewRow()
        '    dr("Name") = objContact.FullName
        '    dr("Mobile:") = objContact.MobileNumber
        '    dr("ContactNum") = objContact.OfficeNumber
        '    dr("Category") = objContact.PersonRelationshipType
        '    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        'Next

        For i = 0 To objSearch.Count - 1
            dr = dt.NewRow()
            dr("Name") = DirectCast(objSearch(i), company.ETMyProperty.Search).SearchByKeyword(searchField, Session("Person"), Session("Office"), Session("Organisation"), _
                                              Session("Role"), company.ETMyProperty.Search.enmSearchType.enmContact, objSearch)
            dr("Mobile") = DirectCast(objSearch(i), company.ETMyProperty.Search).SearchByKeyword(searchField, Session("Person"), Session("Office"), Session("Organisation"), _
                                              Session("Role"), company.ETMyProperty.Search.enmSearchType.enmContact, objSearch)
            dr("ContactNum") = DirectCast(objSearch(i), company.ETMyProperty.Search).SearchByKeyword(searchField, Session("Person"), Session("Office"), Session("Organisation"), _
                                              Session("Role"), company.ETMyProperty.Search.enmSearchType.enmContact, objSearch)
            dr("Category") = DirectCast(objSearch(i), company.ETMyProperty.Search).SearchByKeyword(searchField, Session("Person"), Session("Office"), Session("Organisation"), _
                                              Session("Role"), company.ETMyProperty.Search.enmSearchType.enmContact, objSearch)
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        'Dim objList As New ArrayList
        'For Each objSearching In objList
        '    Dim strText As String = ""
        '    strText += "<a href='#' class=lnks onclick=""window" & objSearching.Return1 & "',750,600)""><b>#" & objSearching.Return1 & "</b>: " & objSearching.Return2 & " " & objSearching.Return3 & "</a><br/>"
        'Next

        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
        Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing

        'serialize dt row to json output
        For Each drow As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next

        Dim str_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented)

        Return str_json

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

That is what I have tried and also the commented code is what I have tried and does not work or it returns the above stated. I am very new to web services and want to convert it to web service but I am struggling. I dont mind C# help!

Comment: Code formatting is missing for last part of the first code sample. I can't fix it because it would be less than the 6 characters edit limit.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?    
Have you tried reducing your web service code until you actually get some expected result? Maybe start with a simple string value, and work your way forward from there.

Comment: @MEMark never tried that, I dont know how to debug properly but ill try to reduce the code. Would be nice if someone helped me but ill figure it out.

Comment: @MEMark with breakpoints at `intResult = ....` part all value's are nothing, then if it gous gown at `dt` is also nothing or 0 and it does not go in the `i = 0 To objSearch.Coun....`

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that there is a lot of code in your post. For someone not familiar with it, it's very hard to understand what is going on. A common thing to do when asking for help is to reduce the code to as little as possible, while still showing the problem. E.g. you will probably get the same error if you just leave `Name` and remove `Mobile` etc. Also remove all commented-out code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code for a webservice should be the same as the code for a non-webservice method, and your problem is that it is not returning the expected value, and you aren't familiar with webservices,  I would suggest an incremental approach.

1. First write a web service that returns a hard code value of the appropriate type.
2. Verify that the service is working and returning the expected results.
3. Write the actual method as non-webservice, but with the same inputs output types.
4. Verify that your method works and produces the expected results.
5. Copy/paste the code from the non-webservice, into the webservice.

Once you are comfortable with writing and consuming webservices, you can go directly to writing the code in a web-method.

I should add, that as an alternative step 5, copy/paste, you can instead have your webservice call your non-webservive method:

```
Private Function ContactGetInfo(ByVal searchField As String) As String
    Return String.Format("user3458266less: {0}", searchField)
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
    Public Function ContactGet(ByVal searchField As String) As String
       Return ContactGetInfo(searchField)
    End Function
```